# Excel-VBA: Find and Replace and Date Formatting from String

Tags: vba, excel, replace, find

```
    ' Try to format the dates
    Range("N:N").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Using this code to try and fix a problem with some downloaded data I don't control. The Table has a Space in front of a date stored as text. e.g. " 04/11/2013"

Doing a Manual Find and Replace in Excel fixes the Issue but I want Pivot the data and group afterwards and when I try and do it with VBA it does two things...

1. It doesn't recognise all records as dates. Some remain as General even though the Cell format is changed. This means the user having to go through each line with F2+Enter, then a lot of messing around with the pivot table.
2. Its Reversing the Day/Month. i.e. the Original Data is 01/10/2013 (Oct 1st) and it converts it into Janauary 10th.

Is there a fix for the Find/Replace or a Way of looping through to fix the Cell Formatting.

Comment: have you tried using `TRIM()` instead?

Comment: Do I have to add and then Cut a Column to do that??
I know I can add a column. Do Trim() and Paste Values and Format as Date. Then Cut the Original Column.. Just Looking to see if there's an easier way.

Comment: @SIEDASC I added a VBA solution that should work in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a none VBA solution you could try the `DATEVALUE` function in this instance.

[DateValue](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx)

Usage would be something like

```
 =DATEVALUE(Trim(A1))
```

or

```
 =DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)
```

assuming your date is in cell A1

---

And for a VBA solution, something like

```
Public Sub ConvertToDate()

Dim endRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dateColumn As Long
Dim dateval As String
Set ws = Sheet1

'set date column (in this case we set column A)
dateColumn = 1

endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, dateColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To endRow

Dim length As Long

length = Len(ws.Cells(i, dateColumn)) - 1

    'just a quick and dirty check to see if there is value data
    'it isn't set to check for numeric data, so if there is some dodgy
    'string data in the cell then it will fail on the CDate line.
    If length > 3 Then

        'store date string (may use Trim() or Mid() etc...)
        dateval = Right(ws.Cells(i, dateColumn).Value, length)

        'convert to date and change cell value
        ws.Cells(i, dateColumn).Value = CDate(dateval)

    End If


Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam Ward. That Worked a Treat. There is no NULL Values in this Date. So the QAD isn't necessary. But It may be useful in other Tables.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Windows regional settings are set for dd/mm/yy.

Do your find/replace

If you need additional processing, run Text to columns on the date column.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent around two hours searching all over google for an answer to this, and nothing was working for me, even though I have my Windows regional settings set for dd/mm/yy. The only VBA function which I've gotten to convert a date into a forward slash dd/mm/yyyy format, is the TextToColumns function.

```
Range("N:N").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)
```

I found the answer from this page - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3522eac-13b1-476c-8766-d70794131cc8/strange-date-conversion-while-using-vba-replace-function?forum=isvvba